# Securely pass the x509 certificate's password to X509Certificate2()?

Tags: c#, security, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, password-protection

I have a c# program with a function `Loadx509Certificate()`
This function returns a new `X509Certificate2` instance, I am passing the file name (PFX) and password to it, looks something like this:

```
return new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "mypassword");
```

My question is, what is a secure way to pass the X509Certificate2 the certificate's password? I know there is X509Certificate2 constructor that takes password as a `SecureString`, however I know that SecureString is used when you create a random kind of password. In my program each user would create their own certificate first, and then run this program that among other stuff loads the x509 certificate, so they would already have created some certificate with their desired password.

I.e. I create a certificate from the command line for example, give it password "Hello", then how else can I pass this password to my `X509Certificate2()` method in my c# program without hardcoding it?
Thank you!

Comment: [SecureString shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md). Just pass it as a normal string. Ultimately a determined hacker could always just decompile your code to find out where you're getting the password from, or read your memory using a debugger

Comment: "without hardcoding it": the same as you get any piece of data from place to place.  Command Line input, a textbox on a UI control, data out of a file...  you just need to get it loaded into a String object (or a ReadOnlySpan<char>) and pass it as a parameter.